# What is the difference between this/that/so much

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "this much", "that much", and "so much"?

Comment: ***this** much - the amount indicated **here***, ***that** much - the amount indicated **there***, ***so** much - an (unexpectedly) **large** amount.*

Comment: @Fumble - This much I know: _There will be so much confusion about this!_ I can at least tell you that much.

Comment: @J.R.: There's [so much of this and that](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22so+much+of+this+and+that%22) here! What about ***the other**?*